# argmax of a function allowing small violations

Tags: math

I have a function that returns an object with the best rating among a set of objects. 
[image]

Now I want to get the object with the best rating which is closest to a certain point. Basically I want to allow a small violation to the formula, such that if o_1 is closer to the given point than o_2 even if 
[image]

[image]

if

[image]

for some small and fixed [image: $\epsilon$.]

Currently I achieve with a about 5 if statements in a program, but I was wondering if there's a way to represent this in a cleaner more elegant way with a mathematical formula perhaps? If you have ever had a problem like this, how did you code it?

Here is a snippet of the code I have, I know there are some refactorizations that could be done to the if statements, I wanted to make the cases clearer. Is there a more elegant way of solving this?

```
public VisualDevice MostSuitableDevice(GameObject u, GameObject t, List<VisualDevice> D)
{
    float maxSuitability = 0;
    VisualDevice mostSuitableDevice = null;
    float epsMaxSuitability = 0;
    VisualDevice epsMSD = null;


    foreach (VisualDevice d in D)
    {
        float suitability = Rating(d, u, t);
        bool closerDevice = mostSuitableDevice != null ? Vector3.Distance(d.GetLightPosition(), t.transform.position) < Vector3.Distance(mostSuitableDevice.GetLightPosition(), t.transform.position) : false;

        if (suitability > maxSuitability && closerDevice)
        {
            maxSuitability = suitability;
            mostSuitableDevice = d;
        }
        else if (suitability > maxSuitability + epsilon)
        {
            maxSuitability = suitability;
            mostSuitableDevice = d;
        }
        else if (suitability + epsilon > maxSuitability && closerDevice)
        {
            closerDevice = epsMSD != null ? Vector3.Distance(d.GetLightPosition(), t.transform.position) < Vector3.Distance(epsMSD.GetLightPosition(), t.transform.position) : false;
            if (suitability > epsMaxSuitability && closerDevice)
            {
                epsMaxSuitability = suitability;
                epsMSD = d;
            }
            else if (suitability > epsMaxSuitability + epsilon)
            {
                epsMaxSuitability = suitability;
                epsMSD = d;
            }
            else if (suitability + epsilon > epsMaxSuitability && closerDevice)
            {
                epsMaxSuitability = suitability;
                epsMSD = d;
            }
        }            

    }
    bool epsCloser = epsMSD != null && mostSuitableDevice!=null ? Vector3.Distance(epsMSD.GetLightPosition(), t.transform.position) < Vector3.Distance(mostSuitableDevice.GetLightPosition(), t.transform.position) : false;
    if (epsMaxSuitability + epsilon > maxSuitability && epsCloser)
    {
        maxSuitability = epsMaxSuitability;
        mostSuitableDevice= epsMSD;
    }

    return mostSuitableDevice;
}
```

Comment: What is a measure for "closeness"?

Comment: Your question  is not clear, as the previous comment implies. Please show your "about 5 `if` statements" to clarify the question and to show that you have done significant work on the problem. More explanation about "closest to a certain point" would also help.

Comment: @MBo just eucledian disntance to a target object/location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find maximum rating `rmax`. Then select the object closest to the given point from all objects `o` with `Rating(o) >= rmax - epsilon`.
Like that:

```
float maxSuitability = D.Max( d => Rating(d, u, t));
float minDistance = float.PositiveInfinity;
VisualDevice mostSuitableDevice = null;
foreach (VisualDevice d in D)
{
    float suitability = Rating(d, u, t);
    if (suitability < maxSuitability - epsilon)
        continue;
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(...
    if (distance < minDistance)
    {
        minDistance = distance;
        mostSuitableDevice = d;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I'm doing exactly that, just in a complicated way. Got any advice on how to improve the code?

Comment: I was not entirely convinced about it at first, but the more I think about it, the more sense it makes. I'm getting slightly different results than what I had before, but it might very well be that what I had before was not entirely correct. Do you see any obvious difference? I will test your solution a little more and then accept your answer

Comment: Think of the following test case: `Rating[i+1] = Rating[i] - epsilon/2` and `Distance[i+1] < Distance[i]`. I think in this case your code would return the last or second-to-last object, even if it has a much lower rating than the first.